# ERC20 Contract transfer call failed multiple times, no idea why

Tags: erc-20, airdrop, transfer, failed-transaction

I found this token that got airdropped on me a while ago, and I don't want it. It was valued at $18 or so.

I decided to sell it, but the exchange had a minimum amount, so I simply bought more so I could get sell the larger sum of the token.

When I tried to send trade back for ETH, the transaction failed. According to etherscan.io, it was a `SafeMath: subtraction overflow`

I did some digging, and tried to use the approve method to allow myself to spend more. No good, the same thing happened.

Then, somewhere I found that it might be the contract calling the method, not me. So I gave the contract an allowance.

No good.

This is quite frustrating, and I'm already down $40 in transaction fees. I just want this pain to end. How can I get this transfer method to *just work*?

Relevant txids (in chronological order):

First failure [0x6bd9dfaee6932d0cc145ba1c8ace1fa5c61fa1c15d7a0233a2242336d723f9ad](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6bd9dfaee6932d0cc145ba1c8ace1fa5c61fa1c15d7a0233a2242336d723f9ad)
Trying to give myself an allowance [0x392fc312e517f2eca885a9c70fbb96b6934ac7932326ddb61aeed1bf437393b3](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x392fc312e517f2eca885a9c70fbb96b6934ac7932326ddb61aeed1bf437393b3)
Second failure [0x2bbe31a3d6f383503e70c40b4ff2f851ca7d0d578e483d566f1a6c9ac1201510](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2bbe31a3d6f383503e70c40b4ff2f851ca7d0d578e483d566f1a6c9ac1201510)
Trying to give the contract an allowance [0xf8d5201c46dcc553bf671d71638a4b3ffaac53457afb093d29cb7ca4a5a54eb0](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf8d5201c46dcc553bf671d71638a4b3ffaac53457afb093d29cb7ca4a5a54eb0)
Third failure (hopefully the final one) [0x4f5d7111df2983970fffb915ca85a06667a0b245f85e7112c3117726841a6e7b](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4f5d7111df2983970fffb915ca85a06667a0b245f85e7112c3117726841a6e7b)

Comment: This error happens usually when ur transfer is bigger than ur balance

Comment: you don't know why are you getting "Safe Math substraction overflow" ? Open the contract source and see it for your self, you are trying to send more tokens than you have. You sent 251996431978566 but you only have 251996431900000 . so there will be a negative balance of -78566 and the contract won't allow this!!  Your greed is punishing you!

Comment: No, you got the numbers wrong. I sent 251996431900000, and I had a balance of 251996431978566. Try reading the balanceOf method using my address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect the token contract itself. There are a bunch of [transactions](https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0xc12d1c73ee7dc3615ba4e37e4abfdbddfa38907e&f=3) with the same problem and, although this is no definitive indicator, [some negative comments](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc12d1c73ee7dc3615ba4e37e4abfdbddfa38907e#comments). Personally I don't think it is reasonable to continue to pour time into this.